# PrimeFaces components don't appear in browser

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using JSF 2.2 in my Project (Tomcat 7.42, Mojarra 2.2.1), and i want to use `p:calendar` from PrimeFaces library. I have included primefaces-4.0.jar into my Project Libraries, and add  `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` namespace, and everything looks ok. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>
    <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date2}" id="popupCal" />  
</h:body>
</html>
```

But, in browser, calendar doesn't appear. Standard `h:` components work great, but from PrimeFaces - nothing works.

I know that PF 4.0 should support JSF 2.2, but i have some issue. 
I appreciate any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem! I am really sorry, but a PrimeFaces' *"Getting Started"* really confused me. The problem is that I had added PrimeFaces as a library into build path of my project, which is not correct. The right way is to put `primefaces-4.0.jar` into lib folder under web project. Things are better now. Anyway, thanks people.

Answer (score 6):

In jsf 2.2 namespaces are changed so you shoud use `xmlns.jcp.org` instead of `java.sun.com`

Comment: Thank you Miroslav, but that wasn't solve my problem. I tried also with my older project (JSF 2.0), where i put primefaces-3.5.jar, but again same problem. I really don't know what's gonna on..